# GAE and HtmlUnit 2.9 - getting exception upon jsxGet_cookie

Tags: google-app-engine, htmlunit

I'm trying to login to google using HtmlUnit in an app in GAE.
However, I keep getting this error:

```
Exception invoking jsxGet_cookie
```

Which is because

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid port: -1
    at org.apache.http.cookie.CookieOrigin.<init>(CookieOrigin.java:58)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.CookieManager.getCookies(CookieManager.java:127)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.html.HTMLDocument.jsxGet_cookie(HTMLDocument.java:638)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:100)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:172)
    ... 94 more
```

This occurs when running in GAE and in my computer.

Has anybody ever seen this kind of error before?
How can I change the default Port?
Are there any workarounds?

Comment: How are we supposed to tell without seeing your actual code?

Answer (score 2):

Change the URL you are fetching to include the default port 80. Example: `http://www.cnn.com` becomes `http://www.cnn.com:80`. There's also a workaround involving overriding classes but I prefer to clarify the URL.

Comment: This is the proper answer. For HTTPS connections use port 443.

Answer (score 1):

I had that problem at first (I have a GWT+GAE app) and I was using this very simple code and I got the js cookie exception and the port:-1 exception

```
    WebClient webClient = Holder.get();
    HtmlPage page=null;

    try {
        page = webClient.getPage(url);
        System.out.println("CRAWLER DONE");
    } catch (FailingHttpStatusCodeException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

     // appengine hack because it's single threaded


    String pageContent = page.asXml();
    webClient.closeAllWindows();
    return pageContent;
```

then I tried the following,

```
    webClient.setCssEnabled(false);
    webClient.setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
    webClient.setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
```

And it just miracusly worked. cheers.

Comment: You need to use the new getOptions() method with these in the recent versions of HtmlUnit. Hope this helps someone as I just ran into it after reading this. webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(true);
webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);